# Extremely simple concurrency-safe web platform

Tags: javascript, database, web, host

I am currently hosting some static content html pages on Amazon's S3. This has been sufficient , but now I am in a position where I need some smarts.

I need to make a server that can hand out jobs when they are requested by clients. I would store some rows of jobs. On a request (made from JavaScript on an HTML page), the server would hand out one of these "ready" resources and mark it as "in-progress". After some timeout, if the job isn't done, return it to "ready". If another call is made (from JS on HTML) from the worker, update to "finished". It has to be able to make all these updates atomically so the same job can't be handed out twice.

One incredibly valuable bonus feature would be if the tech is easy to set up on an Amazon EC2 instance.

So, in summary, I want a platform with as many as possible of:

- easy database access
- **simultaneous-request-safe database access**
- easy request protocol from JavaScript
- can be easily deployed on EC2

Answer (score 0):

I think at this point it's all to play for with cloud hosting. If you ignore requirement (4) for a second, you might want to try [Azure](http://azure.com/) or [OpenShift](http://openshift.com/), as you can access a database on those very easily.